# Can't find xyz without ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the error "Can't find Goal with an ID" but I am not sure where I am going wrong with the code

The models are as follows:

```
A Goal has_many Tasks 
A Task belongs_to Goal
```

The create Task is as follows:

routes.rb is:

```
resources :goals, :only => [:create, :destroy, :show, :index]
resources :tasks, :only => [:create, :destroy, :show, :index]
```

goals_controller.rb#show is:

```
def show
     @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
     @tasks = @goal.tasks
     @task = Task.new if signed_in?      
end
```

tasks_controller.rb#create is:

```
def create
  **@goal = Goal.find(params[:id])** 
  @task  = @goal.tasks.build(params[:task])
  if @task.save
    flash[:success] = "Task created!"
    redirect_to goal_path(@task.goal.id)
  else
    render home_path
  end
end
```

The line in bold is where the error is occurring. I have noticed the following:

```
   @goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id]) does not work either
   @goal = Goal.find(34) works, and so do other integers I enter here
```

I am not sure what the issue is, as I've followed the same process which has worked for me previously but I've done something wrong this time.

I should also state the the tasks form is on the goal#show page.

Comment: The error is "Couldn't find Goal without an ID", app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:6:in `create'. The error is in this line: **@goal = Goal.find(params[:id])**

Comment: --- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
action: show,
id: "34",
controller: goals, an example url is /goals/34

Comment: how do I check which parameters are being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this. I needed a hidden field in the form to pass the id through to the create method in the tasks controller.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :goal_id, @goal.id %>
```

Hope this can help someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `params[:id]` to the `create` action at all.  This is why you're getting this error.

Comment: I am using the build method as shown in the Hartl rails book here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#sec:creating_microposts. From my understanding the difference between create and build is that create saves automatically, where build allows save to be done separately. Can you clarify what you mean with an example? When I do @goal = Goal.find(34) it works

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), for example:

```
resources :goals, :only => [:create, :destroy, :show, :index] do 
  resources :tasks, :only => [:create, :destroy, :show, :index]
end
```

Then you can use:

```
@goal = Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
```

... in your `create` actions.

But note that you would need to change the URL generators in your views for this, for example:

```
new_goal_task_path(@goal, @task)
```

And your form needs to be modified accordingly. You can use things like nested forms very effectively in your case.

Comment: From my (limited) understanding, nested resources get tricky when there are multiple levels for example if a task then had many sub tasks, and sub tasks had further levels. Nested resources would give rise to very long urls

Comment: I've just tried the nested resources approach and I am getting the same error at the moment